# How many comments prompt the "move the discussion to chat" suggestion? (And has it decreased recently?)

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I just got prompted with

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

after six comments (three alternating from me and the OP).

I don't usually go back and forth in comments that much, so I haven't seen it in a while, but it seems like it used to take more comments before that message would show up. My memory isn't that great though, so I'm sure I could just be imagining it.

Comment: It depends on the number of users commenting.

Comment: @Xufox Oh, I didn't realize that. That makes sense, though

Answer (score 1):

Based on the observation and comments on [How do you choose when to show the "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" notice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278872/241919) (MSE), [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300466/241919) states 4 comments from each user on MSE, but [the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278872/how-do-you-choose-when-to-show-the-please-avoid-extended-discussions-in-comment#comment978123_300466) states 3 comments from each user on ruSO. Whether 4 comments on MSE is an exception or not (discussion on meta can't be avoided after all), it should be safe to state that **3 comments are needed generally (so, your's "three alternating comments" is by-design)**

Note that "move the discussion to chat" is only available if there's only 2 users chatting back-and-forth. [More than 2, then the link won't appear anymore.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220798/241919)